How to change the root directory of a Python project?
I have a simple Django project (namely the one from this tutorial).
The main part of the tree looks like this:
.
├── env
├── proj
│   ├── proj
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── base
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
|   ├── db.sqlite3
│   └── manage.py
└── README.md 

In the tutorial the outer proj folder is the root.
In api/views.py is the following import: from base.models import Item
When I print sys.path in settings.py, it contains /path/to/wrapper/proj.
But I would like my root folder to be one level higher.
This is what I did:

go to Settings > Project structure and change content root to /path/to/wrapper
append another .parent to BASE_DIR in settings.py(now BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent)
prepend proj. to imports(now from proj.base.models import Item)

But that does not work: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj.base'
When I print sys.path in settings.py, it still contains /path/to/wrapper/proj.
Where does that actually come from? And how can I change it?
The only effect of the content root in the settings seems to be on syntax highlighting.
Since I changed it, PyCharm considers imports with prepended proj. as correct.
EDIT: It was recommended in a comment to change the source root.
But that change had no effect (except that the root folder is now blue).
(Apparently the source root is implicitly the content root, unless specified otherwise.)


By the sound of it, you may wanna try using os.chdir from the os library.

Don't you need a __init.py__ on all levels then? And maybe you have to move manage.py one level up too.

I thought so too, and added one in the outer proj. But that is not the solution.

see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html, I guess you have to set source_roots: "pyCharm uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports"

I did not find a way to do exactly what I intended.
But it was probably a bad idea anyway.
Thanks to @jhole for the hint at source roots.
A good solution is to use the wrapper as content root,
and the outer proj folder as source root.
(I was not aware, that the two can be separate.)

